# Get min and max column values with single query

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, jpa-2.0, criteria

How to get `min` and `max` value by using jpa and not using native query?

Result must be fetched with single transaction.

Relative `sql` query:

```
SELECT min(price), max(price) FROM product
```

I tried using this code

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.min("price"));
Integer min = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
...
criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("price"));
Integer max = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

but this seems to be too odd to execute it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to use a **[`ProjectionList`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/ProjectionList.html)** with your **[`Criteria`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)**.

Your code would look like this:

```
criteria.setProjection(
     Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.min("price"))
    .add(Projections.max("price"))
);
Object[] minMax = criteria.uniqueResult();
Integer min = (Integer) minMax[0];
Integer max = (Integer) minMax[1];
```

Another option is to use HQL, with `min` and `max` [**Aggregate functions**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation):

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select min(prd.price), max(prd.price) from Product prd");
Object[] minMax = q.getSingleResult();
Integer min = (Integer) minMax[0];
Integer max = (Integer) minMax[1];
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `ProjectionList`, but now my problem is with how I can map min max price directly to Produce entity, there have two regarding properties `minPrice` and `maxPrice`; whether I had tried with `criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class)` but not success.

Comment: @TheHunter Can you please update your question, with your entities? Do you have a Product entity and you want to get another entity as result?

Comment: sorry for typo, I would be prefer to map result to entity `Product`, if not possible then no worries
@chŝdk - thanks for answer, that's all I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a projection list:

```
criteria.setProjection(
  Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.min("price"))
    .add(Projections.max("price"))
);
```